# For loop without incrementing in iteration statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I just wanted to ask whether this is valid as this is the only way my script works as expected:

```
for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j) {
    for (var k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
        $(items.eq(j)).appendTo('.col'+k);
        j++;
    }
}
```

notice the `j` that is not incrementing inside the for statement.

If I increment `j`, the loop ignores every 4th `div` for some reason and I can't explain the reason.

[Here's a **demo** of this script](http://jsfiddle.net/8MenL/4/).

My main question is whether this is a valid method, and if it's not, do you have a better solution for distributing the `div`s in each column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more natural approach would be iterate `items` directly:

```
$(".item").each(function(n) {
    $(this).appendTo('.col' + (n % 3 + 1));
});
```

The modulus operator `%` makes `n` cycle over the values 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 etc.

Comment: You could even get rid of `col` all together and use the index supplied by `each`

Comment: Accepted your answer but I'd like to know if my initial script is valid. I mean without incrementing the `j`. Is this something acceptable in terms of js?

Comment: @otinanai: all expressions in the `for` loop are optional and it's fine to omit any of them altogether, like `for (var j = 0; j < items.length;)`.

Comment: @feeela Almost every day I read a comment or an answer here on SO that says to use js instead of jQuery. Is this a new trend? Performance and things like that? I missed the announcement where they say jQuery is not cool anymore.

Comment: @Rudy In fact jQuery is so cool that I partly forgot how to properly code JavaScript. Using a library has benefits, but if a framework is used just because it could be used, that is the wrong reason. Also ECMA5 has introduced a lot of new methods that are similar to methods the well known JS frameworks provided before they found their way into the standard (e.g. `querySelector()`).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
k=1;
for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
  $(items.eq(j)).appendTo('.col'+k);
  k++;
  if(k==4){
    k=1;
  }
}
```

Comment: much better approach than mine.

Answer (score 2):

a while statement might read better.  other wise *shrugs* if it works it works. to each there own. way to many ways to go about the same thing.

```
var j = 0;
while (j < items.length){
    for (var k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
        $(items.eq(j)).appendTo('.col'+k);
        j++;
    }
}
```

======================

as long as you have the 3 statements or i should say the 2 ""semicolons"" inside the for statement, you could have anything you want...

```
for (;;j++){
}

for ( ;X<K;T){
}
```

sometimes for statements can get rather complex, during the initialization, conditional, and on next irritation statement.  sometimes they can get rather simple. to point they do not always have all 3 notations.

Comment: I appreciate your answer Ryan. I wasn't really looking for alternative solutions but mostly some info regarding the validity of my code. Thanks for your input.

Comment: your original posting is valid. just make sure ya get your 2 semicolons in,  and you can do what you want with the "for" statement.

Answer (score -1):

I am answering to the question in Title. If you want to increment for loop depending on a case you can use the following code.

```
for (int i =1 ;i<10;i=i+0){
if (case)
 do your work here.
  i++;
else
  do nothing here
}
```